# SQLite select rows if timestamp matches today's date

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite

I Would like to select all entries from an SQLite table if the entries timestamp matches todays date.

I am querying an SQLite database as follows:

```
// Tasks table name
private static final String TABLE_TASKS = "tasks";

// Tasks Table Columns names
private static final String KEY_ID = "id";
private static final String KEY_TIMESTAMP = "timestampGMT";
private static final String KEY_DESCRIPTION = "description";


String selectQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + TABLE_TASKS + " WHERE "+ KEY_TIMESTAMP+">=date('now', '-1 day')";
```

This behavior is the closest I have come but I do not wish to select all entries within the last 24hrs. I only want to select if todays date matches the timestamp.

How can I select only the rows in the table who's timestamp matches todays date.

date format is: 2014-07-05 12:59:35 in the database.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

does this work?

```
date('now', 'start of day')
```

Comment: How might I account for timezone? For example easter time is GMT -4. so I need something like date('now', 'start of day -4') but this obviously doesn't work

Comment: Figured it out ANSWER: date('now', 'start of day', 'localtime')

Answer (score 3):

For local timezone:

```
date('now','localtime','start of day')
```