# Android - Select today record from timestamp column in sqlite

Tags: android, sqlite

I want to select today record from database where entry_date (TIMESTAMP)

Comment: What is stopping you? `entry_date >= begin_of_today_as_timestamp`

Comment: actually i am using this query **select  *  from table_Name  where submit_time ='2017-03-22'  **

it is not working

Comment: submit_time = timestamp('yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss')

Comment: Please note that SQLite does not have a separate timestamp type. What is the format of the values in the column?

Comment: Formate of value is just like timestamp yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss

Comment: select * from table where submit_time between ' from_date 00:00:00' and 'to_date 23:59:59'    I tried above query and this is working fine

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
date('now', 'start of day')
```

Source : [SQLite select rows if timestamp matches today's date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24591267/sqlite-select-rows-if-timestamp-matches-todays-date)